# Online resources to deal with Time Zone differences

Tags: online-resources, timezones

**Background**

Time zones can be quite complicated and are common source of misunderstanding when having to plan a meeting when traveling (it happened to a friend and I recently).

- In some places there are summer vs winter times while not in other places.
- Time shift to adjust to another season may occur at different dates at different locations
- Lots of such variation can exist within a single country.
- It may happen that two communities at the same location uses different time zone.
- Some time zone are shifted by 30 minutes only
- etc..

To get an appreciation of the complexity of time zones, I invite you to have a look at [this computerphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY).

**Question**

Can you give me recommendations of websites that allow one to set a time and date at a given location (and community when different communities at the same location use different time zones) and get the corresponding time and date at another arbitrary location?

Comment: Similar question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates.

Comment: The *and community when different communities at the same location use different time zones* is probably too ambitious.

Comment: Have you tried: Google?  And I am not aware of any community in the same location using different timezones.  Furthermore any smartphone running modern OS have a timezone file which sets your time correctly based on your location.

Comment: @Karlson Arizona does not do DST. The Navajo Reservation (within AZ) observes DST. The Hopi Reservation (within the Navajo Res (within AZ)) does not do DST. :)

Comment: @CGCampbell Goole still works.

Comment: Ask over here http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The website [timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/) has a large number of tools for looking up all sorts of information about, well, times and dates.

They have time calculators, time zone converters, time zone maps, a world clock (what time is it in City X?), a meeting planner to help find the best time for participants in multiple time zones, a list of time changes worldwide, and tons of other tools.

Answer (score 0):

Add multiple places to compare times anywhere in the world.
Click on a row, to adjust time for that place.

[Greenwich Mean Time - Time Zone Converter](https://gmt0.com/time-gadgets/time-zone-converter/)

Your choice of places are saved to browser (no need for registration).

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram|Alpha can do date-time conversions, for example to convert between Auckland and Rio de Janerio for today

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=15%3A00+in+Auckland+in+Rio

or to convert for a specific day

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=15%3A00+1+August+2020+in+Auckland+in+Rio